# when I update the stock and price of a product in what tables are updated?

Tags: product, price, upgrade, stock, table

when I update the stock and price of a product 
in what tables are updated?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know product price will be in **catalog_product_enitity_decimal** table and the stock quantity will be in **cataloginventory_stock_item** table.